# only throw error if all API calls in Promise.all fail

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

Before starting an express server JS I want to make three API calls. If any one of them fails I just want to log an error, but if all three fail I want to throw an error and prevent the server from starting.

I have seen I can use `Promise.all`, but I am unsure how to handle the case if one fails. Using the code below if any fail the error will be thrown. How can I limit this to only occurring if all calls fail?

```
const fetchNames = async () => {
    try {
      await Promise.all([
        axios.get("./one.json"),
        axios.get("./two.json"),
        axios.get("./three.json")
      ]);
    } catch {
      throw Error("Promise failed");
    }
  };
```

Comment: What do you expect `res` to be? You might want to look into [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) and [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the fulfillment values, or need just *any* of them, `Promise.any` will work for this use case - it'll reject only if all Promises reject.

```
const firstResolveValue = await Promise.any([
        axios.get("./one.json"),
        axios.get("./two.json"),
        axios.get("./three.json")
]);
```

If you need all result values from the Promises that happen to fulfill, use `Promise.allSettled`.

```
const settledResults = await Promise.allSettled([
    axios.get("./one.json"),
    axios.get("./two.json"),
    axios.get("./three.json")
]);
const fulfilledResults = settledResults.filter(result => result.status === 'fulfilled');
if (!fulfilledResults.length) {
    throw new Error();
} else {
    // do stuff with fulfilledResults
}
```

Comment: thanks very much, and if I want to log an error if one of them fails, what would be the best approach?

Comment: @peterflanagan For `Promise.any`, add `.catch(err => { console.log(err); throw err; })` to all the `axios.get(…)` calls; for `Promise.allSettled`, just loop over `settledResults` and log `result.reason` when `result.status == 'rejected'`.

Comment: @Bergi it's a little difficult to follow from the comment. Would you mind providing this as an answer. Thanks a million, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

If you need just *any* of the results, [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) will work for this use case - it'll reject only if all promises reject.

```
const value = await Promise.any([
    axios.get("./one.json").catch(err => { console.log(err); throw err; }),
    axios.get("./two.json").catch(err => { console.log(err); throw err; }),
    axios.get("./three.json").catch(err => { console.log(err); throw err; }),
]);
```

If you need all result values from the promises that did happen to fulfill, use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled([
    axios.get("./one.json"),
    axios.get("./two.json"),
    axios.get("./three.json"),
]);
const values = [], errors = [];
for (const result of results) {
    if (result.status === 'fulfilled') {
        values.push(result.value);
    } else { // result.status === 'rejected'
        errors.push(result.reason);
    }
}
if (!values.length) {
    throw new AggregateError(errors);
} else {
    for (const err of errors) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    // do stuff with values
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you're actually interested in not having the `catch(e){...}` executed if any of them worked, right? then you can do this:

```
const fetchNames = async () => {
    try {
      await Promise.all([
        axios.get("./one.json").catch(e => console.log(`one failed`, e)),
        axios.get("./two.json").catch(e => console.log(`two failed`, e)),
        axios.get("./three.json").catch(e => console.log(`three failed`, e))
      ]);
    } catch {
      throw Error("Promise failed");
    }
  };
```

The problem above is that if **all of them fail**, then no error is thrown. If you're also interested in that, then something like this should work:

```
const fetchNames = async () => {
    try {
      let success = false;
      await Promise.all([
        axios.get("./one.json").then( () => success = true).catch(e => console.log(`one failed`, e)),
        axios.get("./two.json").then( () => success = true).catch(e => console.log(`two failed`, e)),
        axios.get("./three.json").then( () => success = true).catch(e => console.log(`three failed`, e))
      ]);
    if (!success) throw new Error(`No successful promises`);
    } catch {
      throw Error("Promise failed");
    }
  };
```

Comment: This won't ever run the `catch` block. Not even when *all* the requests fail, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Bergi, you're right. I updated my answer to show a full solution